# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT con headers y cors configurados

Tags: nodejs, express, cors, postman

Tengo un problema con las Cabeceras y CORS, desconozco por qué no están funcionando. Calculo que será algún error simple o algo estará faltando y no me estoy dando cuenta, ya que estoy reciclando código de otro sistema armado y en ese mismo, funciona todo correctamente.

El código en su totalidad trata de realizar un login simple con algún tipo de autenticación de por medio.

Lo que paso de código es una llamada a recuperar los datos, ya sean mediante el req.body o mediante los req.params (o req.query).

La idea de la función getUser es recuperar un usuario mediante su id, si no recibe ningún dato ya sea por ambos medios (params/query o body), debería devolver un mensaje mencionando que falta el dato del ID para poder devolver el dato.

Estoy corriendo en Postman y el problema surge cuando, luego de correr la ruta ya sea con o sin el dato del id, vuelvo a correrla sin reiniciar el servidor, y es ahí donde ocurre el error ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT.

Ya he aplicado la configuración de las cabeceras y CORS pero no dan resultado.

Esto es mi código:

**server.js**

```
'use strict'

// DB CONNECTION
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// APP.JS CALL
const app = require('./app');

// SERVER CONFIG
const port = 8000;

//DB CONNECTION
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/loginapp', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully connected to DATABASE');

        // SERVER SET UP
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Server running in: http://localhost:${port}`);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict'

// EXPRESS CONNECTION
const express = require('express');

// EXPRESS CALL
const app = express();

// ROUTES CONFIG
const user_routes = require('./routes/userRoutes');

// MIDDLEWARES
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

    console.log(res.header());
    next();
});

// ROUTES
const route = '/';

app.use(route, user_routes);

// EXPORTS
module.exports = app;
```

**userController.js**

```
'use strict'

const User = require('../models/userModel');

const getUser = (req, res) =>{

    let id = req.body.id ?? req.query.id;

    if(!id) res.status(404).json({ message: 'Must provide a User ID ' });

    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        if(err) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Request Error' });

        if(!user) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No User with given ID' });
        
        user.password = undefined;

        return res.status(200).json({ user: user });
    });
    
}

module.exports = {
    getUser
}
```

**userRoutes.js**

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const UserController = require('../controllers/userController');

const api = express.Router();
     
api.get('/user/:id?', UserController.getUser);

module.exports = api;
```

**userModel.js**

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**EDIT: Este es el resultado en la consola:**

> events.js:377
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
> at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Jomi\Desktop\loginapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
> at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Jomi\Desktop\loginapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
> at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Jomi\Desktop\loginapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
> at C:\Users\Jomi\Desktop\loginapp\controllers\user.js:96:42
> at C:\Users\Jomi\Desktop\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4931:18
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) Emitted 'error' event on
> Function instance at:
> at C:\Users\Jomi\Desktop\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4933:15
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {   code:
> 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' } [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file
> changes before starting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu `userController.js` estás permitiendo que se pueda responder la petición 2 veces debido a `if(!id) res.status(404).json({ message: 'Must provide a User ID ' });`

Agrega el `return` y no tirará el error:

```javascript
'use strict'

const User = require('../models/userModel');

const getUser = (req, res) =>{

    let id = req.body.id ?? req.query.id;

    if(!id) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Must provide a User ID ' });

    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        if(err) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Request Error' });

        if(!user) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No User with given ID' });
        
        user.password = undefined;

        return res.status(200).json({ user: user });
    });
    
}

module.exports = {
    getUser
}
```

Comment: Sabía que la solución era así de simple. Gracias mil.

Comment: De nada! Ese sentimiento es constante en la vida del programador xD